# Do two or more identical primitive values in JS share the same memory location?

Tags: javascript

Let's imagine we have the following piece of code:

```
let a = 10;
let b = 10
printNumber(10)

function printNumber(num){
   console.log(num)
}
```

Will primitive values `10`, that are assigned to variables `a` and `b` and also passed as an argument to the function `printNumber`, share the same memory location? Will it be effectively just one primitive value 10 stored in memory that can be used in source code unlimited times without the need to bloat the memory?

Answer (score 2):

No, variables `a` and `b` do not share same memory location. Each variable is stored in a stack. So they convey the same value but not same reference.

But, of course, value `10`, in it of itself, is accessed by JavaScript through a specific memory location, which JavaScript knows.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I hope i understood the question correctly)

In your example, you are creating two independent variables `a, b` with the same value `10` - they are assigned during JIT-compilation, so effectively you get 2 memory locations with variables `a, b` coincidentally holding the same value.
The original number itself is not part of the JIT compiled code.
Aside from that, you are creating a function (`printNumber`) with a parameter (`num`) that will be filled during JIT-compilation with the number (again, 10) when invoking the function ('passing the argument'). The parameter is then locally scoped inside the function, and the memory allocated will be garbage-collected after leaving the function.
So, the memory footprint of your JS program is not defined by the use of constants (your primitive values) but instead by the number of variables you declare (and a lot of other things, of course).

To make it a bit more clearer - i added some output to your program along with some variable mutations.

```js
let a = 10
let b = 10
console.log('a init',a)
console.log('b init',b)
printNumber(10)
printNumber(a)
printNumber(b)
function printNumber(num){
   
   console.log('printNumber - num',num)
   console.log('printNumber - a',a)
   a++;
   num++;
}
console.log('a exit',a)
console.log('b exit',b)
```